# How to get the data from repository using viewmodel

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

When using Repository, I would like to get data from an API using `ViewModel`.

However, I do not understand how to configure the `ViewModel` in order to get the data. Let me know if I am doing this right by looking at my code. Additionally, a learning recommendation would be good, which is why I cannot figure it out. Does my basic coding skills need any improvement?

This is the `AppModule`

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesPokemonRepository(
        api: MovieApiService
    ) = MovieRepository(api)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesMovieApi(): MovieApiService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(MovieApiService::class.java)
    }


}
```

```
This is the repository

class MovieRepository @Inject constructor(private val api: MovieApiService) {

    suspend fun getMovieLists(): Resource<List<MoviesItem>> {
        val response = try {
            api.getMovies()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return Resource.Error("An unknown error occurred")
        }
        return Resource.Success(response)
    }

}
```

This is the view model that I am trying to configure

```
@HiltViewModel
class MovieViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: MovieRepository) : ViewModel() {

    var response: List<MoviesItem> by mutableStateOf(listOf())
    val errorMessage: String by mutableStateOf("")
    val isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun getMovies() = viewModelScope.launch {
      val result = repository.getMovieLists()

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `providesPokemonRepository` function. Your repository already does a constructor injection so Hilt will be able to create its instance. Just mark `MovieRepository` with `@Singleton`. Btw do you have any errors in your code? What exactly are you asking help for?

Comment: i want to configure the viewmodel so that i can use it but i dont understand how do i do that @ArpitShukla

Comment: Your ViewModel seems configured to me. It has access to the repository. What other configuration do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `response` should require data in the UI. If you guess wrong, please ignore this answer. Otherwise, the response should be Ui as State.

You have promoted `List<MoviesItem>` as a state to the ViewModel. The data is all in the ViewModel, so access and update of the data all happen in the ViewModel.

If `getMovies()` is a function to update data, then you only need to put the result in `response`.

Response is the state of Ui, and you have used MutableState to wrap it.

```kotlin
var response by mutableStateOf(listOf<MoviesItem>())
    private set
 
fun getMovies() = viewModelScope.launch {
     response = repository.getMovieLists()
}
```

In the Compose function, you can access your latest State through `viewModel.response`.

You can also check the Android Compose documentation on ViewModel

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state